# Tag merge suggestion: VB6-Conversion and VB6-Migration tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

On StackOverflow both VB6-Conversion and VB6-Migration tags exist.  As of this posting VB6-Conversion has 15 questions and 10 of them also have the VB6-Migration tag.  The VB6-Migration tag has 74 questions.

I believe they are the same thing so I propose merging VB6-Conversion into VB6-Migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed. It looks like some of those questions in `[vb6-conversion]` could use a little bit of tag cleanup as well.

A [tag synonym proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6-migration/synonyms) already exists for this as well.

**EDIT:** I have completed retagging `[vb6-conversion]` to `[vb6-migration]`. I also noticed that `[vb-to-vb.net]` is an existing active synonym to `[vb6-migration]`. This request is complete once the proposal above is accepted.